# marker not display on map in htc

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am stuck with this, I have tried every possibility but not success. I have create simple application with map for testing and user can simple touch on map and on that place put the marker. This will work successfully in all device except in htc devices. I don't know how to implement onTouch event for mapview

here is my code for onTouch

```
private class MarkerOverlay extends Overlay{        
    private boolean isMove;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {           
        final int x = (int) e.getX();
        final int y = (int) e.getY();
        if(e.getAction()==1){
            if(!isMove){
                geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "Title", "Description");
                if(mapOverlay.m_overlays.size()>=1){
                    mapOverlay.clearOverlayAll();
                }
                mapOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                if(!mapView.getOverlays().contains(mapOverlay))
                    mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOverlay);

                mapView.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(SimpleMapMarkerActivity.this, "in press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(SimpleMapMarkerActivity.this, "out press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            isMove = false;
        else if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            isMove = true;

        return super.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a minor flaw in your onTouchEvent(..) as you return always super.onTouchEvent(..). As stated in documentation you ought to return true if you handle touch event, while default implementation does nothing more than returns false.

Comment: I have try to return true but the map moving was stop

Comment: Quite obviously yes, if you track whole touch gesture from ACTION_DOWN until ACTION_UP. There's also Overlay.onTap(..) event available, have you considered using it for adding your markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and this solution given by harism

Whenever you just implement the marker with map as just like tap on map and display the market then implement the `onTap(GeoPoint g, MapView mapview)`.

And if you want to implement the marker like moving by user like drag and drop then implement by using `onTouch()`. For `onTouch()` and moving marker like drag and drop check this link

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/mapmarkerexample/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am not sure if it can solve you htc problem. But here's what I did:

I've overridden the dispatchTouchEvent. It works on my Samsung Galaxy s2.

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        xPos = ev.getX();
        yPos = ev.getY();
    }
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (xPos==ev.getX() && yPos == ev.getY()){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Calling onTouch from dispatchTouchEvent.");
            onTouch(mapView, ev);
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I am doint this in mapActivity. not in overLay.

Answer (score 0):

**MapMarkerExample**

This example show you how to draw movable marker on to map. You can darg and drop the marker to change its position. Can be used in any application where u want to take input from user for map location.

Algorithm:

1.) Create a new project by File-> New -> Android Project name it MapMarkerExample.
2.) You will see some default code into your main.xml and android manifest file.
3.) Add internet permission to your manifest file or write following in android.manifest file:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/mapmarkerexample/

Comment: I have this example but bad luck with this also